# Angular i18n Date pipe

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am trying to work with multilingual angular app. I have English and Croatian (hr) language. I am able to see two different translations available for Month names [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.1.x/packages/common/locales/hr.ts).

Now when I use

{{ mydate | date:'MMMM d' }}

In croatian it is giving me **rujna** or **srpnja**, however I am interested in **rujan** and **srpanj**.

What changes should I do to my application. I created one example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m4z8ap).

Comment: It was a silly mistake. I should have used `Month standalone`